# How to update across two tables using a function SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to run an update query which is based across two tables. So i am trying to update my stock level which is a table called workshop. The value i am trying to update it is the stock level from table workshop minus the quantity ordered from an orders table. I am not even sure if this is possible. Any help on this query would be greatly appreciated.

```
 UPDATE WORKSHOP SET STOCK_LEVEL = 
(WORKSHOP.STOCK_LEVEL - ORDERS.QUANTITY_ORDERED)
 FROM ORDERS WHERE WORKSHOP.STOCK_ID = ORDERS.STOCK_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an update with join

```
 UPDATE WORKSHOP 
 INNER JOIN ORDERS ON WORKSHOP.STOCK_ID = ORDERS.STOCK_ID
 SET STOCK_LEVEL =STOCK_LEVEL - ORDERS.QUANTITY_ORDERED
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax in MySQL is:

```
UPDATE WORKSHOP w JOIN
       ORDERS o
       ON w.STOCK_ID = o.STOCK_ID
    SET STOCK_LEVEL = (w.STOCK_LEVEL - o.QUANTITY_ORDERED);
```

Presumably, `ORDERS` could have multiple rows for a given `STOCK_ID`.  If so, you need to pre-aggregate to reduce the quantity for all of them:

```
UPDATE WORKSHOP w JOIN
       (SELECT STOCK_ID, SUM(QUANTITY_ORDERED) as QUANTITY_ORDERED
        FROM ORDERS o
        GROUP BY STOCK_ID
       ) o
       ON w.STOCK_ID = o.STOCK_ID
    SET STOCK_LEVEL = (w.STOCK_LEVEL - o.QUANTITY_ORDERED);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an update join:

```
UPDATE WORKSHOP w
INNER JOIN ORDERS o
    ON w.STOCK_ID = o.STOCK_ID
SET w.STOCK_LEVEL = 
   (w.STOCK_LEVEL - o.QUANTITY_ORDERED)
```

Another way to do the update would be via a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE WORKSHOP w
SET w.STOCK_LEVEL = w.STOCK_LEVEL -
    (SELECT o.QUANTITY_ORDERED FROM ORDERS o
     WHERE w.STOCK_ID = o.STOCK_ID)
```

If you were using Oracle, this might be your only option as Oracle does not support update join syntax.